# ¿Cómo añadir producto desde la paginación al carro de la compra usando ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

Este es mi archivo PHP, que me permite agregar productos a la cesta:

```
<?php
session_start();

$itemId = isset($_GET['itemId']) ? $_GET['itemId'] : "";



if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' and isset($_POST['qtyupdate'])) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['qtyupdate']); $i++) {
        $key = $_POST['arr_key_' . $i];
        $_SESSION['qty'][$key] = $_POST['qtyupdate'][$i];
    }

} else {
    $qty = isset($_POST['qty']) ? $_POST['qty'] : 1;
    if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
        $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
        $_SESSION['qty'][] = array();
    }
    if (in_array($itemId, $_SESSION['cart'])) {
        $key = array_search($itemId, $_SESSION['cart']);
        $_SESSION['qty'][$key] = $_SESSION['qty'][$key] + $qty;
    } else {
        array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $itemId);
        $key = array_search($itemId, $_SESSION['cart']);
        $_SESSION['qty'][$key] = $qty;
    }
}
header('location:cart.php');

?>
```

Este es mi código `ajax`, funciona bien cuando el botón añadir esta en una pagina individual y si el único botón que existe:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.close', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.alert-success').hide();
        $('.alert-danger').hide();
    });

    var frm = $('#frmCart');
    frm.submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = frm.serialize();
        formData += '&' + $('#addCart').attr('name') + '=' + $('#addCart').attr('value');

        var url = "addItem_cart.ini.php";
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: url,
            data: formData,
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            let res = JSON.parse(data);
            if(res.status){
                $("#wrapp-basket").load(" #wrapp-basket").fadeIn();
                $("#qty").load(" #qty").fadeIn();
                $('.alert-success').fadeIn();
                $('.alert-success').html(res.message).delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);
                $(".alert-success").append("<button class='close' type='button'><span aria-hidden='true'>x</span></button>");
            } else {
                $('.alert-danger').fadeIn();
                $('.alert-danger').html(res.message).delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);
                $(".alert-danger").append("<button class='close' type='button'><span aria-hidden='true'>x</span></button>");
            }
        })
        .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
            alert("Ajax Request fail");
            //$('.warning').fadeIn();
            //$('.warning').html(textStatus).delay(3000).fadeOut(3000);
            //console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
            //console.log("Request failed: " + textStatus );
        })
    });
});
```

El problema es cuando tengo varios botones de añadir productos en este caso desde un paginador, el botón no funciona o más bien el `ajax` deja de funcionar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así es el `HTML` de los botones cuando están en la paginación:

```
<form><div class="shipping">
                        <label></label>
                        <em>$13,00</em>
                        <input type="hidden" name="itemId" value="2">
                        <input type="submit" id="addCart" class="addCart buy" name="addCart" value="Añadir a la cesta" formnovalidate="">
                    </div></form>
<form><div class="shipping">
                        <label></label>
                        <em>$8,00</em>
                        <input type="hidden" name="itemId" value="2">
                        <input type="submit" id="addCart" class="addCart buy" name="addCart" value="Añadir a la cesta" formnovalidate="">
                    </div></form>
<form><div class="shipping">
                        <label></label>
                        <em>$10,00</em>
                        <input type="hidden" name="itemId" value="2">
                        <input type="submit" id="addCart" class="addCart buy" name="addCart" value="Añadir a la cesta" formnovalidate="">
                    </div></form>
```

El botón de añadir esta dentro de un `form` es porque envió otros datos adicionales de otros campos `input, select, radio`

Como le puede decir a `ajax` o `jquery` que datos debe tomar y que funcione al presionar el botón añadir teniendo en cuanta que todos tiene el mismo nombre: `id="addCart" class="addCart buy"` ya que se encuentra listado en una paginación.

Comment: ¿Tu php devuelve código de estado si es correcta o incorrecta la petición?

Comment: @FernandoCarrascosa Hola, no entiendo en qué sentido, mi código es lo que hace al inicio es agregar un producto al carro de la compra y si existe pasa al `else` a actualizar es hasta donde entendí en un tutorial en Youtube.

Comment: La cuestión está en que si lo que quieres usar es `AJAX`, no quieres recargar la página. Haces una petición a un `endpoint` y este debe devolverte unos datos, si la operación ha sido exitosa, si ha fallado, por qué ha fallado...

Comment: @FernandoCarrascosa Entiendo, eso no está definido en mi código porque no se está utilizando Ajax, entonces lo que toca hacer es crear un `echo""` para obtener un mensaje de respuesta.

Comment: Deberías devolver un texto en formato JSON (por ejemplo) y un código HTTP de respuesta https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.http-response-code.php mira esto a ver si te puede servir. Lo del "echo" no es mala idea combinado con esto.

Comment: @FernandoCarrascosa pero es necesario todo ese proceso, porque el código funciona bien, lo único que se desea lograr es que se envíe la petición por medio de Ajax y actualizar todo el cuerpo HTML body o un div específico donde estén variables que muestra información del carrito de la compra.

Comment: ¿Y cómo puedes informar al cliente (navegador) de que el proceso se ha completado para cambiar esos divs que quieres cambiar?

Comment: @FernandoCarrascosa En este caso donde se oculta el botón comprar por otra información como la respuesta que me dió Wilfrido con eso es un claro ejemplo de que la petición fue procesada o al menos da entender que el producto ya fue agregado correctamente...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95432/discussion-between-fernando-carrascosa-and-lily).

Answer (score 1):

La variable `$_SESSION['cart']` es un array donde vas guardando los productos que ya tienes agregados en la carretilla

entonces:

```html
//negamos la busqueda
if (!in_array($itemId, $_SESSION['cart'])) {
        echo "
          <div class='buy-now'>
              <a href='../updatecart.php?itemId=11'>Buy now</a>
          </div>
          ";
    } else {
        echo "
        <div class='buy-now'>
            <span>Producto ya añadido</span>
        </div>
        ";
    }
```

Comment: Hola gracias, disculpa me podrías ayudar indicándome como agregar los productos en Ajax sin hacer que se recargue la página cada vez que doy clic en `<a href="updatecart.php"></a>`

Comment: Has podido solucionar lo de  agregar los productos en Ajax  ?

Answer (score 0):

No se si estoy en lo correcto te mostrare lo que yo haria:

primero le agrego un id al div y en el href que sea una funcion javascript.

y en la funcion javascript hago una peticion ajax

```html
<div class='buy-now' id='button-add'>
              <a href='javascript:agregar_al_carrito('11')'>Buy now</a>
    </div>
```

```js
function agregar_al_carrito(producto_id){

$.ajax({
            url: 'tu url donde procesas agregar al carrito',
            type: 'GET', // o POST como la recibas 
            data: 'id=' + producto_id,
            dataType:'json',
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#button-add").html("Procesando");
            },
            success: function (json) {
                if (json.success) {
                    $("#button-add").html("<span>Producto ya añadido</span>");
                } else {
                 //muestras de nuevo el boton si da un error agregar

            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });

}
```

En tu archivo php donde agregas el id a la session  debes responder con un true en formato json puede ser echo

Ahora para actualizar alguna tabla donde muestres el carrito puedes usar load

```js
$("#id-de-tu-div").load('url donde cargas la tabla con los articulos de tucarrito'); // carrito.php, etc
```

quizas me linchen soy nuevo respondiendo aqui asi que me perdonan si cometi alguna infraccion al publicar esta respuesta.

Eso es usando ajax de Jquery es una idea, suerte.

Answer (score -2):

No sé si te sirve pero lo más sencillo que se me ocurre es enviar un parámetro por el request y según el valor mostrar el botón o no.

En le php:

header('location:cart.php?ocultar=1');

Y luego en la página:

```
<div class="buy-now">
<?php if (isset($_GET['ocultar'])) { ?>
    <span>Producto ya añadido</span>
<?php } else { ?>
    <a href="../updatecart.php?itemId=11">Buy now</a>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Para el caso la página es php. No sé si te sirve.

Comment: Tiene gracia votar en negativo, es decir "la respuesta no es útil", pero no explicar por qué no es útil la respuesta y más todavía no proponer ninguna solución. Desde el anonimato es fácil

Comment: No he votado en negativo pero desde ya te digo que por parámetro no es buena idea. por que te expones a manipulación de url

Comment: Admito lo que dices - lo de la manipulación. Aun así, sin ser nada elaborada, es una respuesta. Opino que cuando algo se da como "no válido" habría que argumentar.

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev Gracias por su respuesta, pero no me ayuda, si vuelvo al producto no me va ocultar la información, de todas formas gracias por el tiempo :)

Comment: Tampoco yo he votado negativo, pero siendo o no elaborada e implicando mejores o peores prácticas esta respuesta **NO** responde lo que el OP pregunta, que es poder hacerlo mediante `AJAX`